# How to make jenkins job wait for other job triggered by same event?

Tags: jenkins

job_A and job_B gets triggered for gerrit_change_x - this works.

I want job_A to do a Verified+ on gerrit_change_x only after job_B finishes successfully, I cannot use "Trigger build on other projects" on job_A to trigger job_B because I need it to get triggered by a gerrit event so I can use all GERRIT_XXX env variables in job_B as well. job_A can start after job_B or at the same time, but will have to wait for job_B's result before the last "execute shell" step which does Verified+.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to have a second job triggered by gerrit. You do the trigger parametrized down stream job with the same params you have in gerrit triggered job only if the original job build is successful. I do this way. The 1st build once succeed set the verify label and trigger down stream. If failed ,set verify as minus and do not trigger down stream.  It's enough to see there is something wrong at what exactly step of verification.